# Kendo UI Core Chart

Tags: kendo-ui, asp.net-core-mvc, kendo-chart

Where can I find breaking changes when upgrading to kendo ui core?

For e.g. in previous version

```
Html.Kendo().Chart()
.Name("test")
.Legend(l => l
  .Position(ChartLegendPosition.Top)
  .Color("#111111") //This gives error .Color is not available
)
.ChartArea(chartarea => chartarea.Border(3, "#111111", ChartDashType.Dash)) //This gives error No overload method 'Border' takes 3 arguments
```

I am unable to find how to fix them and there are other controls with similar issues. So I would also like to know if there is any where I can look for all such breaking changes?

Comment: What color element of the legend do you want to set the color of? The border or the background?

Comment: It is legend label color, please see this link https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/api/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/ChartLegendBuilder

Comment: Try my updated answer below

Comment: Thank you very much your suggested edited change works!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see breaking changes listed in the documentation [here](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/backwards-compatibility/overview), sorted into years.

Edit:
Based on the API reference found [here](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/api/chart), it seems that your code should look something like this:

```
Html.Kendo().Chart()
.Name("test")
.Legend(legend => legend
    .Position(ChartLegendPosition.Top)
    .Labels(labels => labels.Color("#111111"))
)
.ChartArea(chartarea => chartarea
    .Border(border => border
        .Width(3)
        .Color("#111111")
        .DashType(ChartDashType.Dash))
```

Edit #2: Changed to set legend label color.

Comment: Thank you for your link but unfortunately it does not contain what I am looking for.